# How to update email address to receive expiry notification from letsencrypt?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to update the old email address which was being used to recieve expiry notification from the amazing Letsencrypt. However, I did not find a way to do it amazingly :O.

What I did try however: I deleted the old certificate in the hope that certbot would have asked me regarding the new email but the fact it didn't (poor me)

I deleted the old certificate using this command

```
certbot delete
```

then I chose the domain which I would like to delete.

Then I regenerate a new letsencrypt certificate which was a success no errors found and the website was still online without any further certificate issue (prost to that!):

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx -d thecompany.com
```

But then however, CERTBOT did not ask me for a new email address! (omg!)

And now I don't know what to do, feels like banging my head to the wall won't help, so, I let my fingers dance on my keyboard and asked this question to the nicest folks at here :).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html):

```
--update-registration
                    With the register verb, indicates that details
                    associated with an existing registration, such as the
                    e-mail address, should be updated, rather than
                    registering a new account. (default: False)
-m EMAIL, --email EMAIL
                    Email used for registration and recovery contact. Use
                    comma to register multiple emails, ex:
                    u1@example.com,u2@example.com. (default: Ask).
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick answer. I was looking at the doc but I was hesitate because I have multiple domains here, so if I ran the update using the command above, would it update the email addresses for other domains as well? I expect not ...

Comment: AFAIK the mail address is bound to the account, not to a domain. So yes, this will affect all certificates registered with that account.

Comment: so, in my situation, this one server was maintained by another system admin who is already not working anymore and he could not be contacted. I am now concerned...what is mean with account? can I know how to get more info about this account, such as which domains are related to the account?

Comment: Again, quote from the documentation: `To view a list of the certificates Certbot knows about, run the certificates subcommand`. If that lists all certificates bound to  the account, or only the ones on the server certbot runs on, I don't know.

Comment: thanks for your answer. One more thing, the question above was for server A, I am managing another server (B). I generated letsencrypt cert on server B with email letsencrypt@thecompany.com. Then I tried to update the registration on server A, and yes, certbot told me it has successfully changed the email address to letsencrypt@thecompany.com, however, at the next line it saysthat it has failed to subscribed letsencrypt@thecompany.com, I dunno if this is the normal expectation?

Answer (score 6):

```
--update-registration
```

is no more a valid argument, the below command worked for me to update/change the email id.

```
sudo certbot update_account -m <mail_id>
```

Below is the snippet of the `sudo certbot --help` command about **manage accounts**.

```
manage your account:
    register        Create an ACME account
    unregister      Deactivate an ACME account
    update_account  Update an ACME account
    show_account    Display account details
  --agree-tos       Agree to the ACME server's Subscriber Agreement
   -m EMAIL         Email address for important account notifications
```